# Codeigniter dropdown throws error and no data is displaying

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below codeigniter code I have placed controller, model, view. In  which I have implement college name dropdown, but it throws error

> Undefined variable: select_options, Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach()

And there is not data in dropdown. 
Please help me to solve the issue.

**Controller**

```
function add_content() {
    $data = array();
    $this->is_logged_in();
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $data['select_options'] = $this->membership_model-> validate();
    $this->load->view('login_form', $data);
}

function validate_credentials() {       
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query) { // if the user's credentials validated...
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );

        if($query->num_rows()>0) {
            $status = $query->row()->account_status;
        } else {
            $status = ''; 
        }

        //Account active
        if($status == 'active') {
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site1/members_area');
        } else if ($status == 'inactive') { //Account In active
            $this->inactive();
        } else { // incorrect username or password
            $this->invalid();
        }
    }   
}
```

**Model**

```
function validate() {
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $this->db->select('college_name'); 
    $this->db->from('membership');
    $this->db->where('college_name');
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');

    foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $data[$row['college_name']];
    }

    return $query;
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 
    echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');
    echo form_input('username', 'Username');
    echo form_password('password', 'Password');
    echo form_dropdown('college_name', $select_options);

    echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
    echo anchor('login/signup', 'Create Account');
    echo form_close();
?>
```

Comment: are you sure you're calling add_content function not the other one!

Comment: validate() is returning $query. It should return $data.

Comment: i have add this function to the controller

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $this->db->select('college_name'); 
    $this->db->from('membership');
    $this->db->where('college_name');
    $query = $this->db->get('membership');
    $data = [];
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
      $data[$row['college_name']] = $row['college_name'];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Array should be like this

```
$options = array(
              'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
              'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
              'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
              'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
            );

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large');

// Would produce:

<select name="shirts">
<option value="small">Small Shirt</option>
<option value="med">Medium Shirt</option>
<option value="large" selected="selected">Large Shirt</option>
<option value="xlarge">Extra Large Shirt</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how to make changes in view part

Comment: @user2991258 no need to make change in view part just change your validate function

Comment: i am asking how to implement this view part from the above u post.

Comment: below is just example how you should implement